# Significance of coherence frequncies

Tags: time-series, signal-processing, fourier-transform

I have used the spectrum package in R to find the coherence between two time series. I can currently find a significance level using the $c=\sqrt {1-\alpha^{(\frac{1}{n-1})}}$ for each individual frequency. However, I am only really interested in 5 of these frequencies. Is it possibly to combine coherence values of 2 or more frequencies? i.e is it possible to calculate just a singular value to summaries a number of combined frequencies.  If so how would one do this and are there any estimates for what would happen to the significance levels after they have been combined?